Script to show an Android phone directory
Is there a way I can write a script to show this directory?
It is on an android phone
mtp://SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_R92W40PMAFV/Internal storage/DCIM/Camera/



  adb shell 'ls -d /SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_R92W40PMAFV/Internal storage/DCIM/Camera/

This does not show the directory.

If you install adb you can pass Linux-like commands to the phone such as
adb shell 'ls -d /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*' (use your own directory of course)
which gives output like
/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/PXL_20230502_174319911.jpg
/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/PXL_20230502_175427120.jpg
/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/PXL_20230919_011232807.jpg


Something is not working.adb shell 'ls -d  /SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_R92W40PMAFV/Internal storage/DCIM/Camera/

@fixit7 Do a ls at the top level. I don't have to put in the name of the phone. Mine starts at /sdcard just like I wrote. If you say what the actual error is, that would help. You may also have to do something about the space in Internal storage. I also put a * at the end, you didn't. And you left off the end quote. Try doing it like the answer says.

What do you mean top level? /SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_R92W40PMAFV/ls
Alarms   Audiobooks  Documents  Movies  Notifications  Podcasts    Ringtones
Android  DCIM        Download   Music   Pictures       Recordings
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_R92W40PMAFV/Inter
